# Unity3D file explorer on Microsoft Hololens?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, hololens, unity3d-gui

My goal is to read a XLSX file and use this to generate objects in Unity3D. However this app is for a hololens. It is possible to let the game ask the user to select a file which it should import (at runtime)? like how a regular windows forms app opens an explorer window and lets you browse for a file.

so, just to clarify, what i DONT want is to import the XLSX file as an asset before building the app (because the game shouldn't be limited to just use that file!).

Let me know if the question isn't detailed enough, I'll try to specify it more if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unity itself doesn't have any way to implement a filebrowser on runtime however people have made their own versions of a filebrowser which you could use. Something like the [ImprovedFileBrowser](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ImprovedFileBrowser) by Daniel Brauer. Which was inspired by a [Filebrowser](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/FileBrowser) made by AngryAnt

> Note: The [ImprovedFileBrowser](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ImprovedFileBrowser) uses the [ImprovedSelectionList](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ImprovedSelectionList)  which you will also need to get it to work.

Comment: I'm guessing you dont know if this will work for a HoloLens? I can't really find a list of supported libraries or something along those lines

Comment: That would help me put big time! Thanks in advance

Comment: Alright, it doesn't have any problem building, so that's a plus. However you will probably have to hack around a bit in how the GUI is created because it looks like it's making it in the camera overlay layer, which doesn't work for HoloLens. But I think if you're able to create that GUI in a canvas which is on world space you would probably be able to use it

Comment: Thanks! Monday I'll be able to test this!

Comment: Cool, let me know how it turns out